# Get current page ID for hook

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

I use a hook from the plugin Formidable Pro (`frm_to_email`) where I absolutely need to have the ID of the current page (for Advanced Custom Fields). As the code is located in `function.php`, it seems impossible for me to retrieve it. What can I do to get this value?

```
function custom_set_email_value($recipients, $values, $form_id, $args){
    global $post;
    $profil_obj = get_field('profil_obj', $post->ID); // If I put the ID directly (10 for example), it works

    if( $form_id == get_field('popup_form_id', 'option') && $args['email_key'] == get_field('popup_email_id', 'option') ){
        if($profil_obj) {
            foreach( $profil_obj as $post) {
                setup_postdata($post);
                $recipients[] = get_field('profil_email', $post->ID);
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return $recipients;
}
add_filter('frm_to_email', 'custom_set_email_value', 10, 4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get the post ID at that stage from the URL, with [`url_to_postid()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/url_to_postid):

```php
<?php
$scheme  = (!isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) || $_SERVER["HTTPS"] === "off") ? "http" : "https";
$url     = "$scheme://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$post_id = url_to_postid( $url );
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried either of these methods:

```
global $post;
echo $post->ID;
```

or

```
global $wp_query;
echo $wp_query->post->ID;
```

Alternatively, if you know the ID of the page you are using the form on, you could add the page id as a hidden form field value. So, if for example, you had 2 pages on which the form appears, you create two identical forms but with a hidden field that has a value equivalent to the id of the page the given form will appear on.

Comment: Hi, neither of the two solutions works unfortunately. Regarding the idea of the masked field, why not, I must see if I do not fall into the same problem because I will use another hook : I can't duplicate the form, there are too many pages. Thanks for the search trail. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add global $post to your function.

```
function custom_set_email_value($recipients, $values, $form_id, $args){
    global $post;
    $profil_obj = get_field('profil_obj', $post->ID); // If I put the ID directly (10 for example), it works

    if( $form_id == get_field('popup_form_id', 'option') && $args['email_key'] == get_field('popup_email_id', 'option') ){
        if($profil_obj) {
            foreach( $profil_obj as $post) {
                setup_postdata($post);
                $recipients[] = get_field('profil_email', $post->ID);
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
    return $recipients;
}
add_filter('frm_to_email', 'custom_set_email_value', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to specify it in my example code.
This unfortunately does not work.